# Обособление запятыми

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*...с которыми он и его(,) ставшие впоследствии величайшими и легендарными(,) последователи столкнулись там...*

Нужно ли обособление (зпт в скобках)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имеет смысл изменить структуру предложения:

.**..с которыми он и его последователи, ставшие впоследствии величайшими и легендарными,  столкнулись там....**

Приведенный вариант неестественен и  неудобен для прочтения и понимания.

Что касается заданного вопроса, то  **определительный  оборота после притяжательного местоимения не обособляется согласно правилу**:

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109

4. Определительный оборот, стоящий после определительного, указательного или **притяжательного** местоимения, тесно примыкает к нему и запятой не отделяется: **Ваш проверенный на практике метод** заслуживает внимания.

Comment: Изменённый вариант лучше, конечно, но и авторский правилами нормируется: распространённое определение, выраженное причастным оборотом, не обособляется, если стоит перед определяемым словом (последователи).

Comment: Вопрос вроде бы был о возможности обособления причастного оборота после притяжательного местоимения "его".  Оборот в этом случае не обособляется, но, возможно, у автора есть желание  выделить его как дополнительное сообщение (но это возможно только при изменении структуры предложения).

Comment: Не знаю,с чем связано его желание, может, просто с незнанием правил обособления распространённого определения. Он же спрашивает, нужно или не нужно обособление, а Вы ему отвечаете, что вариант не нормируется правилами. Почему же? Нормируется: нет обособления, потому что определение стоит перед определяемым словом, не относится к личному местоимению и не имеет добавочного обстоятельственного значения.

Comment: У Розенталя есть правило, позволяющее или не позволяющее обособлять причастный оборот, стоящий после притяжательного местоимения  перед определяемым словом? Рассматривается такой вариант? Я именно такую структуру имела в виду, когда говорила, что вариант не нормируется.

Comment: В данном случае не имеет значения, после чего стоит оборот, - в любом месте, и после притяжательного местоимения тоже. Не обособляется, если нет других причин обособления - уточнения, присоединения, вводной конструкции, пояснения.

Comment: Розенталь считает, что имеет значение, "после чего стоит оборот". Ответ исправлен, тема указана